# OneDrive SDK Canceling Operation

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, onedrive

I'm using `OneDrive Sdk`, reading from doc, only `Copy` operation that can be canceled.

[OneDrive SDK Copy](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/items.md#copy-an-item)

Is there any work around to enable `Cancelling` from other operation like `Download` and `Upload`, I can find a way to pass `CancellationToken` for those.

```
public async Task Download(string itemPath)
{
   var driveClient =
     await
         OneDriveClientExtensions.GetAuthenticatedClientUsingOnlineIdAuthenticator(new[]
         {"wl.signin", "onedrive.readwrite"});


    var item = await driveClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(itemPath).Content.Request().GetAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cancellation operation is not currently supported in OneDrive SDK for download and upload. But it seems the SDK team is working on it. You can follow the open issue: [Cancellation support?](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/issues/18) in GitHub to get more information.

To support cancellation operation in UWP, you can try to implement you own download and upload method with [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient). This is a modern HTTP client API for Windows Store apps and supports cancellation and progress. For more information about how to use this class, you can refer to the 
official [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient).

Comment: Can you eleborate more on how to implement my own download and update method ?